Unblock Stage When Any Manual Job Is Executed From a Multiple Manual Job
I have a scenario where I have multiple manual jobs in one stage.  Is there a way to complete the stage if ANY of the manual jobs is executed successfully.
Gitlab version: 16.8.0
Example
Screenshot 1

As you can see in Screenshot 1, I have executed job cd-publish-patch.   At this moment, I do not want the pipeline stays in Blocked state, I want it to complete the pipeline.  User can click on any of the cd-publish-xxxx.  I tried adding allow_failure: false in all the publish job, but that doesn't block the pipeline.  It just consider the pipeline successful even the manual jobs are not executed.  Look at Screenshot 2
Screenshot 2

I'm not sure if this is even possible.  Just checking if anyone has a solution to the scenario I have described.

Is there any other stage after publish that you want gitlab-ci to continue?

Nope, there is no other stage after the publish stage.  I don't mind to consider any dummy post stage if you can solve the publish block state.  My requirement is that the publish stage should unblock if i executed any of the 3 job major, minor and patch

There isn't any straightforward solution for this. I was thinking on using rules for jobs in publish stage and then omitting the jobs that are not needed.

Do you have any example you can provide using rules ?

I have added as answer.

You can use rules to achieve it:
cd-publish-patch:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "cd-publish-patch"
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
cd-publish-minor:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "cd-publish-minor"
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ '/minor publish$/'
cd-publish-major:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "cd-publish-major"
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION =~ '/major publish$/'

Here is the list of all variables that you can use.

Don't think this may work for example, during the current pipeline, the CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE is 'Abc', after click on any of the cd-publish-xxx, the message won't change for the current commit, it will only change after adding to a new commit.  This will work if it fires a new pipeline.  What i want to achieve is everything on the current pipeline.  Or maybe I'm missing something.  You have a sample pipeline to show it works ?

This is all for before pipeline starts, not during the pipeline.
